# Why would my computer suddenly and without reason become stuck in a "HDD-access" loop?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I've got a Thinkpad X201 tablet which is around 3 years old, never reinstalled windows; so I am aware it must be quite clunky and slow like a tortoise and I'm sort of ok with that for the time being.

However one thing I don't get and can't tolerate is that very often (every day at least once), it suddenly starts accessing the hard drive and wouldn't stop: the HDD LED stays on, and the computer takes litterally (I timed it) 2min to bring the task manager up - forget about any other task.

I've thought about unsufficient RAM, but the task manager says I have 900MB or so cached, and around 200MB free (out of 3GB), so it doesn't seem to be the issue. The CPU does not seem to be hogged by any process in particular. I can't access the resource monitor, I've stopped waiting after 10min and did like I always do: think really hard about throwing the computer far through the window as a catharsis, and decide to push hard on the power button as if I was strangling it (I know, very bad for the HDD).

I'll certainly reinstall Windows anyway sometime but that won't tell me what the issue was - I'm more curious about the cause so if you have any idea please let me know.

### Edit:

Here is CristalDiskInfo's report:
[image]

Comment: What you describe is an indication your HDD is starting to fail

Comment: Backup your data and be ready to replace your hard disk. Have you run SMART diagnostics on your hard disk?

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like you got a lead. I'm not sure what "pending sector count" means but it doesn't sound good. I've updated my post with the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Do like I **always** do.. and decide to push hard on the power button as if I was strangling it (I know, very bad for the HDD)."

Seems to me like symptoms of a failing HDD. You should diagnose your hard drive health and post the results. Here's a live program that MAY tell you more: http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

My go to is always to run a bootable HDD scanner. Check out one of the following: [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/), [HDAT2](http://www.hdat2.com/), [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/), [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). I suggest one of the boot CD's since they have several tools/HDD scans in one. There are also HDD Scans made by individual HDD manufacturers, you can look into a prog/iso made for your specific brand of drive.

Depending on how long you've been pretending to "strangle" your computer the HDD scans may correct soft bad sectors that have cropped up through your manual hard shutdowns. If this is the case the scans should be able to easily correct them and there shouldn't be very many (more than a ~dozen is bad) otherwise if the issue is "hard" bad sectors you'll have many flagged sectors, some may not be correctable, etc... if that's the case then prepare for the inevitable.

See hard vs soft bad sectors:
http://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/

Comment: Thanks a lot (special mention for the software recommendations), you three seem to agree on the cause and it is not looking good - I'm not sure what "pending sector count" means but it doesn't sound good. I've updated my post with the report.

Comment: "pending sectors" means there are sector/s that can't be relocated. When a sector goes bad the HDD's firmware tries to automatically mark it as "bad" then assign/replace it with another sector (why HDD's have ~465GB rather than 500GB) but this doesn't always take place depending on the firmware and type of sector. The problem with CrystalDisk is that it only READS the HDD info, it doesn't try anything. The other scans mentioned will try to correct the bad sectors or relocate. They'll also tell you specifically where and how many sectors are the issue. Effectively giving you a better diagnosis.

Answer (score 4):

This happens because the harddrive was requested to read or write data from a sector that is bad, and rather than marking the sector as such and moving on, it is struggling because it's not just that sector, it is the harddrive as a whole. Yes, that means your failing, and this normally happens very fast.

**These steps should be taken as fast as possible:**

1. Take your drive out, and mount it as a secondary drive on a computer
2. Copy out what you can. Try to get any important data first. (In the case of a head crash, the more you use your drive, the less likely it is to salvage anything from it)
3. If you are unable to get some files, in step #2, try to recover parts of any vital files with a recovery tool, or even better: Make an image of the drive as complete as you can with tools such as `ddrescue`, and work on that image instead.
4. Get a new drive, and discard the old one

Comment: Thanks a lot, you three seem to agree on the cause and it is not looking good - I'm not sure what "pending sector count" means but it doesn't sound good. I've updated my post with the report.